# Can Sharepoint document library support folder versioning?

Tags: sharepoint, versioning, document

Will the sharepoint document library support folder versioning?
For example, I have a document library with a folder say, 'My Folder'. Can i create a new folder with the same name so that there will be multiple versions of that folder.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SharePoint does not support versioning of folders. Enabling versioning support on a document library only affects the documents and not the folders.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think so.

But you can have versions of the files in the folder.