# Disable versioning in specific folder sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, version-control, sharepoint-2010

Is possible disable versioning in a folder which the library versioning is activated?

Comment: Versioning is a feature of sharepoint libraries. You can only enable/disable them for the entire library. It is not possible to disable versioning for a specific folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, as Flowerking said versioning is a feature of Sharepoint library , so you can enable/disable it for the entire library.

ANother thing is Folder cannot have versioning but the content avaliable inside it will have version settings as per the Library version settings

[Can Sharepoint document library support folder versioning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764450/can-sharepoint-document-library-support-folder-versioning)

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for answer, but i want disable versioning control inside folder, not for folder, understand?

Comment: Thats not possible as i said , it is the Library level setting not item level